# Selecting text between Brackets in an input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

With `$("#TextInputElement").select()`

I am able to select a text (mark it) in an in an input text field.

Now I only want to select the text in between brackets in that input field.
I have the regular expression `match(/-[^-]*-/)` to select, but how would I apply this to only select the text inside the input field between brackets?

[noselect]textToBeSelected[/noselect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use createTextRange/setSelectionRange

[Example](http://webcloud.se/article/Selecting_text_with_JavaScript/) showing how to use them in a cross browser manner

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var text = $("#TextInputElement").select();
var pattern = /\[(.*)\]/g;
text = text.match(pattern);
```